# Python Discord Bot that responds to keywords while not being case sensitive

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm very new to python as in I'm making this bot for fun, but I've been trying to make a simple discord.py bot that will respond to keywords that aren't case sensitive as well as detect the word in a message. I've been able to have it be non case sensitive, but the main issue that I'm having is being able to detect the keyword in the message along with that.

The snippet below is what I've used for being non case sensitive, but I just haven't figured out how to allow it to find it in a message.

```html
if message.content.lower() == "ok":
        await message.channel.send('Ok')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the string is already in the message:

```py
if "ok" in message.content.lower():
    # do stuff
```

However, this will match things like `ok`, `ok and also this` (these are good), but also in the middle of words: `uhueanbfononoeiw**ok**ajjasoifjojq`.

If you want it to match only word boundaries, you can do:

```py
if "ok" in message.content.lower().split(' '):
    # do stuff
```

If you want to be even more fancy you can look into [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).